# how to validate conditionally using yup and formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I would like to validate two fields using the yup with the condition of anyone is required, I mean there are the username and email fields are there but user have to enter anyone, how to validate it with the yup

```
      const ValidationSchema = function (values) {
        return Yup.object().shape({
          email: Yup.string()
            .required('email is required!'),
          username: Yup.string()
            .when('email', {
             is: true, 
             then: Yup.string(),
             otherwise: Yup.string().required('Please Enter Username!'),
           }),
        })
   }
```